# Why is'nt this jquery code registering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have the following code which is'nt registering:

```
var Num1=1;

 $(".rightbutton").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
    $("#contenttable tr:visible").slice(1,9).hide();
    $("#contenttable tr:hidden").slice((8*Num1), (8*Num1+7)).show();
    var Num1 = Num1 +1;
    });
```

The problem with the code is the operation done within the second slice() method. I know this because when i substitute those operations with their expected results for i = 1 and then i = 2, the code works as expected. 
This leads me to believe my formatting of the Num1 variable is incorrect. I'm new to jquery so this might be the case. Please let me know.

Comment: Just to add, i normally wouldn't bother people with such simple issues. But I think i'm missing something important since I've been on this problem for hours.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
var Num1 = Num1 +1;.
```

To

```
Num1 = Num1 +1; // or just Num1++
```

You are making a new local variable each time (notice the `var`) other than updating the global one.

Comment: Thankyou, i'm quite frustrated i didnt notice that sooner!